# Why don't we have an instruction called LDAX H in 8085 microprocessor?

Tags: 8085, instruction-set

Whereas we have instructions such as LDAX B , LDAX D !!!

Comment: Because instruction sets are usually reflecting the hardware architecture. Some registers are wired to some hardware. Some are not. And the real answer to "Why" is  "Because it is designed this way and proven to do it's job well"

Comment: The _real_ answer is "because Intel's opcode names suck".

Answer (score 5):

You DO have the equivalent of LDAX H in the 8085. But it's written as

```
MOV A,M
```

Because M is defined as "the address pointed to by the HL register pair".

So, for the same reason,

```
MOV M,A
```

is the equivalent of STAX H

Comment: The syntax is different because the LDAX and STAX instructions are extensions to the original 8008 instruction set.

Answer (score 0):

As @Finbarr said, data pointed by the register pair HL is mnemonically treated differently than `DE` and `BC`. There're two things to consider in the scope of the question:

**1. Why word `LDAX` and what does it mean?**

Word `LDAX` is just a mnemonic, and set of characters corresponding to the specific CPU opcode. In general, it could have been anything developers wanted, distinct from other mnemonics to differentiate with other CPU operations. LD most probably means *load* and A means accumulator. What X stands for should be *indirect*. Why not LDAI you would ask? This is actually a good question, and most probably developers of assembler mnemonics wanted differentiation with `MVI` and `LXI` instructions.

To understand it better you must look into the history of Intel 8-bit processors, their opcodes and mnemonics used. The set of related CPUs are 8008 -> 8080 -> 8085 and fork to Z80. There was specific instruction set in [8008](http://datasheets.chipdb.org/upload/wepwawet/8008_(1978)%20Datasheet.pdf), and developers were trying to extend it to [8080](http://www.hartetechnologies.com/manuals/Intel/Intel%208080%20System%20Manual_a.PDF) and then to [8085](http://www.eazynotes.com/notes/microprocessor/notes/opcodes-table-of-intel-8085.pdf). Z80 is different story, it has its own set of mnemonics, very similar to the 8080's, but different, without this `M` register.

8008 allowed indirect load only from one register pair - `HL`, and it was called register `M`. When accessing this register CPU was actually accessing external memory at the address set in CPU register pair `HL`. There were no other indirect registers, thus `M` seemed to be the good choice standing for *memory*.

8080 is an extension to 8008, and now it allows loading accumulator from memory address pointed by register pairs DE and BC, however what would be the virtual register to use in mnemonic? M1? M2? MD? MB? And developers decided, for new 8080 CPU opcodes, to introduce new commands eliminating confusion and make code designed for 8080 look similar/portable to 8008, thus assembly mnemonics set of 8080 being a superset of 8008, and not new set.

In contrast, in Z80 assembler all indirect access is made uniform, and programmers explicitly state which register pair is used: e.g. `LD A,(HL)`, `LD A,(DE)` and `LD A,(BC)`, and machine code generated by the compiler will be the same to `MOV A,M`, `LDAX D` and `LDAX B` respectively.

**2. Why HL is not in the list of LDAX?**

First, for compatibility reasons with the 8008/8080 assembler; second reason is that `M` (or `(HL)`) has real functional reason to exist. There're a number of operations, when CPU uses its RAM *logically the same way* as its internal registers, thus `M` functionally is really one more register addressed by the pair `HL`. These commands are (in mnemonic): `ADD M`, `ADC M`, `SUB M`, `SBB M`, `INR M`, `DCR M`, `CMP M`, `ANA M`, `ORA M` and `XRA M`.

Let's take `INR M`. Its opcode is `00_110_100`, where leading `00` and trailing `100` define operation to increment contents of the 8-bit register, and `100` in the middle is identification of indirect access of the RAM using HL register. So, opcode `00_111_100` corresponds to `INR A` (`111` identifies accumulator register) and opcode `00_001_100` corresponds to `INR C` (`001` identifies register C).

Functionally, operation `LDAX H` exists in the processor, and its opcode is the same as `MOV A,M`, but your assembler may not (or - to your surprise may!) accept this mnemonic.